# Joining user table with user_follows table twice

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to find all users that the current user is following and that is following the current user. I connect the users-following in a users_follow table.

From my user model:

```
has_many(:user_follows, :foreign_key => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy
has_many(:reverse_user_follows, class_name: 'UserFollow', :foreign_key => :user_b_id, :dependent => :destroy)
```

So i want to select all users that have a user_follow entry with user_id = current_user.id and user_b.id = the-user-i-am-searching for, as well as a entry with user_id = the-user-i-am-searching-for, and user_b.id = current_user.id

Can i do this with activerecord or am i better of doing it in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
User.all(:joins => [:user_follows, :reverse_user_follows ], :conditions => ["user_follows.user_b_id = ? AND reverse_user_follows_users.user_id = ?", current_user.id,  current_user.id])
```